# Inject a page break before numbered list in MS word

Tags: vba, regex, microsoft-word-2010, find-and-replace, linebreaks

I have a document with 70+ questions in it.  Most of the questions were numbered using MS Word's numbered list.  I need to inject a page break before each of these questions so that they are on their on page.  It needs to be injected before because each question also contains a numbered list within it of options to choose from pertinent to the question.  Is this possible using MS Word's built in find and replace to inject the page break and also keep the numbering?  Can this be built in Visual Basic as a reusable function?

Example:

{Initial state all on one page}

1. What is your gender? (Select one)

   1. Male
   2. Female
2. What is your ethnicity? (Select all that apply)

   1. Caucasian
   2. Black
   3. Hispanic

Desired result after find and replace regex or visual basic code snippet:

{Page Break}

1. What is your gender? (Select one)

   () Male

   () Female

{Page Break}

2. What is your ethnicity? (Select all that apply)

   [] Caucasian

   [] Black

   [] Hispanic

Answer (score 1):

You could record a macro in Word of your inserting a page break, but since you would have to have your cursor on the line where you want the page break, I don't think you would save much time. Once you have the document formatted the way you like, you could save it as a Word template so that publishing newer versions is more efficient.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.